# Would my Google Analytic data and report deleted too if remove its owner?

Tags: google-analytics

I have a Google Analytic which is created by `a@gmail.com`.

Now, I want to delete my Gmail account `a@gmail.com`. Before deleting it, I have added one user role `b@gmail.com` (admin/user management) which has fully administrate.

If I delete my Gmail account `a@gmail.com`, would my Google Analytic data and report deleted too?

Answer (score 1):

**No**, because you have added another account `b@gmail.com` to your Google Analytics account.

I would suggest before deleting the account `a@gmail.com` remove it from Analytics account. You can remove it from yourself, or you can login Analytics account with `b@gmail.com` and remove `a@gmail.com`. Now you can [delete user](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009702?hl=en#Delete) `a@gmail.com`, your  Google Analytic data and report will be safe.